# Runtime changing the state of CapsLock in JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, toolkit

I know we can retrieve the state of CapsLock by:

```
boolean isOn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

and i know it is possible to change the state of it to on by:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, true);
```

and off by:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, false);
```

but my main problem is that the mentioned codes just work at the beginning of the application's execution. suppose the situation that user is typing in a `TextField` ( either `Swing` or `JavaFx` based ) and during typing he/she accidentally presses `Caps Lock` Key of keyboard, so in this case the mentioned codes are not helpful because they can just check the state of `capslock` at the beginning.

Maybe there are new options in JavaFX, i don't know, any way...

Is there any way to turn off `capslock` whenever user attempts to turn it on, especially during typing process ?

Comment: If you need the text to be in uppercase, the you could either use a DocumentFilter (Swing) or convert the resulting text to uppercase when you need to use it

Comment: yes it is possible to use uppercase and lowercase methods, but i need to turn `capslock` off :(

Comment: Why? As a user, that would be considerably annoying

Comment: the main reason is for language shifting, suppose that your native language is Persian, and your keyboard and system just support English, so you can get a english character for example "a" and you can convert it to ش ( actually by converting in ASCII codes )
Persian language has more alphabet than English, so for covering this problem you need to use  (Shift + English character)...and so on

I hope my explanation was understandable for you

Comment: Then in Swing, use a DocumentFilter

Comment: What about JavaFX, have you got any suggestion?

Comment: In JavaFX, the equivalent is a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html)